# Affect multiple elements of same ID?

Tags: jquery, loops, repeat

I'm trying to perform an effect targeted at objects with the same `id`, but it only works on the first one:

```
$("#continue").addGlow({ .. etc.. });
```

How do I carry forth with this?

Comment: You should use a class. Its not good to have more than 1 instance of the same ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. This is a consequence of the HTML standard. As Peter mentioned in the above comment, you should use classes. Not only is what you're doing bad practice, but it could have unspecified behavior on old, mobile, or even some mainstream browsers.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/struct/global.html

> id = name
>   This attribute assigns a document-wide name to a specific
>   instance of an element. **Values for id must be unique within a
>   document.** Furthermore, this attribute shares the same name space as
>   the name attribute.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

if you must use ID, you can do

```
$('[id="continue"]').addGlow({ .. etc.. });
```

THIS WILL WORK, I TESTED!

Answer (score 0):

An id can only be validly applied to a single element.  If you want to classify a group of elements then you should use a class, not an id.

```
$(".continue").addGlow({ .. etc.. });
```

Trying to use an id across multiple DOM elements will just lead to pain and frustration.